# Angular - Module '{0}' is not available! error due to folder name

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Running into a weird issue with loading an Angular module.

I have a file structure like so

```
-ng-app
    -app
        -account
            accountCtrl.js.coffee
        -auth
            authCtrl.js.coffee
        -other_folders
        app.js.coffee
```

and I'm loading accountCtrl and other controllers like so

```
#app/app.js.coffee
angular.module("app", [
    'ngResource' 
    'smart-table'
    'checklist-model'
    'ui.router'
    ...
])

#app/account/accountCtrl.js.coffee
@app = angular.module('app')
app.controller 'accountCtrl', ($scope, $state) ->
   ....

#app/auth/authCtrl.js.coffee
@app = angular.module('app')
app.controller 'authCtrl', ($scope, $state) ->
   ....
```

But then accountCtrl throws an error

> Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.

I know the syntax is correct, because I'm loading a a few dozen other controllers with the same syntax. So I started playing around with different scenarios.

1. I deleted the 'account' folder

   > No error thrown, other controllers load normally
2. I renamed account folder to z-account

   > No error thrown, all controllers including accountCtrl load normally

So the error only occurs when the folder is named 'account' and is the first file in the 'app' folder. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Where do you declare the module? Must have dependencies argument in a declaration. Also bad practice to assign module to variable

Comment: @charlietfl updated with module declaration. Why is it a bad practice to assign the module to a variable?

Comment: See [John Papa Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#modules) . Note that in your example you overwrite the variable `app` effectively wiping out previous controller

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that it's bad practice when there's only one component in a file. But I'm grouping multiple controllers in a single file. It's an approach that works for his team and projects, my team and projects have a different approach. But thanks for the link.

Comment: But you are creating your own collision by overwriting the same variable. part of the reason it's a bad practice

Comment: It's a local variable defined once in each file. There's no collision. In any case we're getting off topic.

Comment: Not local unless there is an IIFE wrapping contents of each file. Variables are not local to file...they are local to scope they are declared in. Did you even try removing the variable?

Comment: @charlietfl you're absolutely right. I've changed the variables to declare the module directly and the error still occurs.

Comment: Sounds like a server routing issue perhaps. Does file actually get included in page and is contents what is expected. Check in browser dev tools network or sources

Comment: @charlietfl it seems to be be an issue with the files in app/account being included in the final js file BEFORE the app/app.js.coffee file. In which case it seems to be a problem with the Rails asset pipeline and not angular.

Comment: That's what I was implying with it being server side issue. i don't know Rails but symptoms don't suggest client side or code issue

Comment: @charlietfl many thanks for the help. And sorry for the attitude I was giving you earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails asset pipeline includes javascript files aphabetically, and app/account.js.coffee was being included before app/app.js.coffee, hence the missing module error.

Two solutions possible:

1. prefix files with an underscore to ensure it loads first like so:

   ```
   _app.js.coffee
   ```

Or

2. Remove

   ```
    //= require_tree .
   ```

in application.js and include files manually.